# Staic Route in Windows 7 without Gateway address

Tags: windows-7, windows, static-routes

Is there a way to add a static route in Windows 7 to an interface adapter that does not have a gateway?  I have an adapter that does not need internet access (no router) and one that does.  All the examples of the persistent route seems to require a gateway address

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can add a static route for a remote host/network without configuring a Default Gateway address on the adapter.

Semantically speaking, the route is a gateway, although it's not the Default Gateway.

You don't need a Default Gateway to communicate with remote hosts/networks. You need a route for those hosts/networks. A Default Gateway is used when a more specific route to those hosts/networks doesn't exist. You'll be creating a specific route so a DG isn't needed.

A gateway is a route to a specific host/network. A Default Gateway is a route for all of those hosts/networks for which a more specific route doesn't exist. In both cases they are both gateways.